# jQuery - Adding active class to submenus in a menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a sidebar menu which I am using for navigation throughout my website and I am wanting to be able to dynamically add the active class to the appropriate menu item. I've tried using the code bellow but It doesnt seem to be doing anything.

```
    var page = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    $('ul li a[href="'+ page +'"]').parent().addClass('active');
    $('ul li a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == page;
    }).parent().addClass('active');
```

I might have my syntax wrong for the selector so below I have included a snippet of the sidebar.

```
    <div id="sidebar" class="nav-collapse ">
        <ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">
            <li>
                <a href="dash.php">
                    <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                    <span>Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="sub-menu">
                <a href="javascript:;" >
                    <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
                    <span>Tools</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="sub">
                    <li><a href="index.php">Uptime</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: are your href absolute paths?? You might need to split the window location to get the last value or something. I mean, your window.location will never be 'index.php'.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that the easiest way would be to filter the collection of `<a>` elements to see which an `href` property equal to the current page, then add the 'active' class-name to the closest ancestor `<li>` element:

```
// caching the URL of the page:
var pageURL = document.location.href;

// selecting all <a> elements within the element with the
// id of 'nav-accordion'; then using the filter() method
// to filter the collection returned by the selector:
$('#nav-accordion a').filter(function (index, anchorEl) {

    // only those elements for which this assessment returns
    // Boolean true will be retained.
    // here we test that the 'href' property (not the attribute),
    // which is an absolute URL, is equal the current page's URL:
    return anchorEl.href === pageURL;

// for those elements remaining in the collection we navigate to
// each retained element's closest ancestor '<li>' element and
// and then add the 'active' class-name to that <li>:
}).closest('li').addClass('active');
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`document.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location).
  - [`URLUtils.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils/href).
- jQuery:

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Answer (score 0):

`window.location` does not return a string. If you open your browser's developer tools and inspect it you will see it is an object. Not sure what value you're after, but I think you would start with the `pathname` property e.g., `var path = window.location.pathname;` then do some regex to get the page name if necessary.

Comment: Yes, to get the proper name I had to use `var page = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$( "#sidebar" ).on('click', function() {
$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

I hope this helps